# UIButton addTarget does not work inside UITableViewCell class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, uikit

Suppose you have a class

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell
{
    var button: UIButton =
        {
            let obj = UIButton()
            obj.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            obj.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapBtn), for: .touchUpInside)
            return obj
        }()
    
    init()
    {
        super.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "identifier")
        //other configurations for UI
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    @objc func didTapBtn()
    {
        print("btn tapped")
    }
}
```

If your table view deque a reusable cell, and you then tap the button it does not work. Here `var button` has to be a `lazy var button` in order for it to work. (or you must specify the addTarget when self is created in initializer)

By this I understand that whenever we addTarget to a UIButton, self object has to be initialised at the time of adding target (so it does find self in target).

But when we write the similar code for UIViewController, like

```
class Controller: UIViewController
{
    var button: UIButton =
        {
            let obj = UIButton()
            obj.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            obj.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapBtn), for: .touchUpInside)
            return obj
        }()
    
    init()
    {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        //other ui configurations
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    @objc func didTapBtn()
    {
        print("btn tapped")
    }
}
```

Then it is now not necessary for a UIButton to be lazy var, we can keep `addTarget` as it is in trailing closure of `var button`, where that closure even runs before initializer and that button target will still work.

What is actually going on behind the scenes, the first way in `UITableViewCell` class has to be the correct behaviour according to me as self should not be available, before the initialization of the object is done. But how does that `addTarget` works for a `UIViewController` class ?

Comment: Show the lines where you read table view data.

Comment: I've found the reason behind this. In my above code, when I am adding the target to a UIButton, I am using self where self is not initialized at that point. Somehow the swift compiles it, but it should give a compile time error for this code. The solution is using a lazy var instead of var, so that the variable is initialized when self is properly initialized.